# Accessing property of nested array error with Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript.

Playing with types I got stuck trying to resolve the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'number | (number | number[])[]'.
> Property '0' does not exist on type 'number | (number | number[])[]'.

Here is my code

```
let arr = [2, [22, [222]], 2222];

console.log(arr[1][0]); // 22
```

I searched around and found examples for objects but I don't know how to do it with a nested array.

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to check if it's an array before indexing into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes a lot of sense since the typesystem is not certain that the index `arr[1]` you are accessing is definitely an array. It could equally be likely the `arr[1]` is actually a number.

This is the exact advantage typesript gives you. In plain javascript you could write `arr[0][1]` and you would have no compilation error. You would, however, get a nasty error at runtime since `arr[0]` is not an array at all.

You should only be able to use `arr[1]` as an array type after ensuring `arr[1]` is actually an array. So you must do something like:

```
if (Array.isArray(arr[1])) {
  console.log(arr[1][0]); // 22 - No typescript error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me.

Before Error:

```
const slug = props.data[0].attributes.slug;
```

After adding check "Array.isArray":

```
const slug = Array.isArray(props.data) ? props.data[0].attributes.slug : null;
```